# Can an xml file be part of a QT qrc resource file

Tags: opencv, pyqt, pyinstaller

I built a PyQt application to showcase object detection. The detector was trained using haar classifier, whose ouptut is a cascade.xml file.

I tried to package this application using pyinstaller. However, before this, i made a resources.qrc file which i compiled.

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
<file>cascade.xml</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

My issue is that when i use this resource, via

```
:/cascade.xml
```

the file is not read.
What can i do to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to create a python module from your .qrc file with `pyrcc`

```
pyrcc5 resources.qrc -o resources.py
```

The output of `pyrcc` then needs to be imported into your python code

```python
import resources
```

Then you should be able to access the resource through `':/cascade.xml'`. In some cases it may be necessary to use `'qrc:/cascade.xml'`

The resource path must still, however, be treated like a file on disk. In order to access its contents you will need to read from the resource. Here's an example of how to read and parse it using `lxml`

```python
import lxml.etree as etree
from PyQt5 import QtCore

# Import the resource module create by pyrcc
import resources

# QFile knows how to read Qt resources
xml_file = QtCore.QFile(':/cascade.xml')

if xml_file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly):
    # Read the QFile and convert QByteArray output to python string
    xml_str = str(xml_file.readAll())

    # parse the xml document from string
    xml_tree = etree.ElementTree(etree.fromstring(xml_str))

    xml_file.close()
```

Comment: According to page 181 from Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt: The Definitive Guide to PyQt Programming, i was able to avoid using the cascade as a qt resource.  `cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier()
fullpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
cascade.load(fullpath + '/' + 'wf_cascade.xml')`